# WPF/MVVM: Sync scrolling of two datagrids in different views

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid, mvvm

I have two datagrids side by side bound to different data tables and each with their own view.

The datatables both have the same number of rows, and I want both grids to maintain the same scroll position.

I am having trouble finding a way to do this using MVVM... anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!
-Steven

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at codeproject [Scroll Synchronization](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ScrollSynchronization.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This was exactly what I was looking for, already have it implemented and working :)

Answer (score 8):

I was able to overcome this issue via some reflection hacks:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="DataGrid1_ScrollChanged" />
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid2" />
```

and the code itself is:

```
    private void DataGrid1_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HorizontalChange != 0.0f)
        {
            ScrollViewer sv = null;
            Type t = DataGrid1.GetType();
            try
            {
                sv = t.InvokeMember("InternalScrollHost", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, DataGrid2, null) as ScrollViewer;
                sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(e.HorizontalOffset);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for reflection hack. used this in conjunction with the codeproject article to achieve a working attached property implementation for WPF Datagrid

Answer (score 4):

The Scroll Synchronization project doesn't work for Datagrid because it doesn't expose ScrollToVerticalOffset

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've used so far is to use the `VisualTreeHelper` class to find the correct `ScrollViewer` object (grid or no grid). I've used this in several projects.

Try this if any of you need it:

```
private static bool ScrollToOffset(DependencyObject n, double offset)
{
    bool terminate = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(n); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(n, i);
        if (child is ScrollViewer)
        {
            (child as ScrollViewer).ScrollToVerticalOffset(offset);
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (!terminate)
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(n); i++)
            terminate = ScrollToOffset(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(n, i), offset);
     return false;
}
```

Note: I typically use ListBox classes and would pass it directly to this function.

Happy programming :)